# What happens to media files when a WhatsApp user recalls the message?

Tags: android, messaging, reverse-engineering

WhatsApp has the ***"Delete For Everyone"*** feature that makes it easy to delete messages you did not intend to send to the other user.

[image: WhatsApp users get this message when the other party recalls a previously sent message]

For text messages, this recall is easy, but what about Video, Photo or other message resources? In Android, whatsapp messages and resources get saved on the device. Is that deleted too using unlink function that is available in many *nix platforms?

Anyone who did static analysis care to comment?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not WhatsApp's technical support team. Related: [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Comment: I was looking for a Quora like answer which I found below.

Comment: Unlike Quora, this site is only about Software Engineering as defined in our [help/on-topic]. This includes questions about design-level problems you encounter while developing software. This does not include speculation on the inner workings of existing software, nor does it include customer support style questions. While you don't “need” WhatsApp's customer support to answer your question, that answer would not be out of place in their support center.

Comment: I would guess it is exactly the same as for text messages: if the user has already copied the content out of WhatsApp, then there is absolutely nothing whatsoever that WhatsApp can do about it. If the user hasn't copied the content out of WhatsApp yet, then WhatsApp still has full control and can delete it. There is zero difference between text messages and media messages.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Apparently there is an answer here:

[Does delete for everyone feature on WhatsApp work for videos or pictures which were already downloaded by the recipient on their phone?](https://www.quora.com/Does-delete-for-everyone-feature-on-WhatsApp-work-for-videos-or-pictures-which-were-already-downloaded-by-the-recipient-on-their-phone)

> No, If the person has backup to Google Photos or Drive option enabled
>   for their WhatsApp the photos does not get deleted even if you delete
>   it for everyone. It remains on the cloud.
>
> However if the backup to cloud option isn't enabled the photo gets
>   deleted from the recipients smartphone too even if downloaded!

So unless there is a better and/or updated answer with newer versions, will just have to take this one.